# Paragraph ended before \type@get was complete

Tags: errors, formatting, pdftex

I'm trying to use the TeXshade package to typeset biological sequence alignments, but for some reason LaTeX is throwing an error whenever I try to include the TeXshade environment.

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{texshade}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Title
\end{center}

\begin{texshade}{q1alignment.msf}
    \setdomain{1}{80..90,100..110,120..130}
    \showruler{1}{top}
    \hidenumbering
    \hideconsensus
\end{texshade}

\end{document}
```

I'm also getting the following error as well:

```
\begin{texshade} on input line 15 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

Any advice on how to fix this or another way of typsetting alignments in LaTeX would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: I tried with the example `.MSF` file that comes with the distribution and I got no error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was due to a malformed file produced by software unrelated to TeX and friends.

Comment: That actually wasn't the case? The file was perfectly well-formed for most applications, but included charecters that function as escape charecters in LaTeX, causing LaTeX/TeXshade to throw an error.

Comment: As far as I know, `//` is not a special character for (La)TeX

Answer (score 0):

Answer for anyone interested:

Error seemed to be comming from a `//` charecter in the .msf file, inserted by EMBL's MView alignment format conversion tool.

(Thanks, egreg)

Comment: You should really disclose this kind of information in the question (by posting the `.msf` file), otherwise it's impossible to answer... it's just guesswork.